# Accessing Rails assets ignoring the scoped locale in the URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, localization, asset-pipeline

I set the background of my homepage via JS-jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.nonsignedin-home').closest('html').css({
    'background-image':"url('assets/my_background.jpg')",
    'background-repeat': "no-repeat",
    'background-size':'cover'
  });
});
```

Everything was working well until I introduced locales in my app. Since I decided to scope my URL's with the selected locale:

```rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope ":locale" do
    #My routes here
  end
end
```

Now totally understandably there's a routing error:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/es/assets/my_background.jpg"):`

since the URL is locale-scoped. And my background image is located in `assets/images/my_background.jpg`.

The question is, how can I bypass this `es` scope in my URL when accessing assets? I have no interest in having different background for each locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('.nonsignedin-home').closest('html').css({
    'background-image':"url('/assets/my_background.jpg')",
    'background-repeat': "no-repeat",
    'background-size':'cover'
  });
});
```

Does that help? Note the extra '/' in front of your assets path.